NodePorts on K3s Cluster
I have a K3s cluster set up consisting of 3 Raspberry Pi’s each running Raspberry Pi OS light (Raspbian). In a virtual machine on my Windows PC, running Ubuntu Desktop, I have setup rancher to manage the K3s cluster. Now I deployed PiHole on the cluster using the GitHub repo from Colin McCarthy. I have installed it using the manifest files from the repo and afterwards configuring it via Rancher.  For pihole-https I configured the port 30080 on the IP 192.168.0.180 (which is the IP of the Master-Plane of my cluster). I did similar changes for DNS and DNS-UDP for DNS Requests but with port 30053.
Now I am probably just not thinkig about it in the right way but now I can access the PiHoles webinterface on the IP of every node of my cluster and I can also make DNS requests on port 30053 on the IP-Address of every Node of my cluster. I now want to let my FritzBox 6690 point to it as the network wide DNS server but in the configuration menu of the FritzBox there is no option to specifically set a port. Because of this the FritzBox is always using the standard DNS port 53. In the cluster configuration for the PiHole deployment under networking (again referring to the image) i can only choose ports from 30000 to something in the region of 32000 and not low ports such as the standard DNS port 53. Because of this I cant manage to let the PiHole listen on port 53 on the “public“ IP address, and with public I mean the IP-Address outside of the cluster, and thus I cant let my FritzBox use it as the standard DNS server.
I am really just getting started with clustering and K3s and Rancher and do not know much about it. I thought of simply rerouting traffic from port 53 to port 30053 on the nodes but that turns out to not be that easy either.
I hope that there is a better and not even that complex way of achieving this.
